# Xcode 4.6 Compiling Non-Thumb Architecture

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.6, thumb

I've built a project in Xcode with the intention that it won't be compiled for the Thumb instruction set - armv6 or armv7. I know that not compiling for the Thumb instruction set in armv7 isn't optimal, but I'm satisfying a client's request.

Does anyone know how I can test the build, which consists of a lib.a file and a .h file, in order to see if it was, in fact, built without the Thumb instruction set?

Just for the record, I've added a user-defined build setting for GCC_THUMB_SUPPORT and set it's value to NO. In addition, I've added -mno-thumb to OTHER_CFLAGS in the build settings.

Comment: Can't you just dump assembler from the compiler?

Comment: Better still: Xcode provides the option of compiling and showing individual files as ASM code, or even running a decompile on a single file.  It's all up in the top-left corner of the editor on the little button next to the scope bar.